# How to return different type from Asp.net MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am posting data to Controller . if data is valid a pdf file is downloading.
if data is not valid I am loading same view again.

Note: I search that during the downloading a file when can't load a view or redirect to another Controller .
below is my Controller Code!!!!

```
public  ActionResult Index(Rentwithholding obj)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        this.TaxPayerName = obj.TaxPayerName;
        this.TINNumber = Convert.ToInt64(obj.TINnumber);
        this.TaxPeriodID = obj.TaxPeriodNumber;
        findBussnissType(Convert.ToInt64(obj.TINnumber));
        getalldates();
        if (obj.TenPercentRent != "")
        {
            this.TenPercentRent = Convert.ToDouble(obj.TenPercentRent);
            this.CalculteTenPercentTax();
        }
        if (obj.FifteenPercentRent != "")
        {
            this.FifteenPercentRent = Convert.ToDouble(obj.FifteenPercentRent);
            this.CalculteFifteenPercentTax();
        }
        this.PrintPdf();

    }
    else
    { 
        ViewBag.message = "Incorrect Captcha";
        return View("Index", obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question here, you are telling us what the code does, but not where **or what** the error is

Comment: above code give the error because in the if block I didn't return Actionresult. and I want in the if block to return void and the else block to return Actionresult.

Comment: Ah right, the best option in that case is to create something like a success page, which you redirect to - you can have `return View("Success");` and then just a basic page with your layout and an alert saying "PDF now printing"

Comment: but during downloading we can't do anything.. we can't redirect to another controller and we can't load a view as will.

Comment: @NasimBahar What if you just `return null;` after printPdf

Comment: @AhmedRagheb thank you.. it is working..!!!!!

Comment: Ok can I add it as a answer and you verify it for help other with same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return null after PrintPdf();